# How to unmarshall XSD fields to private fields instead of protected using xsd OR xjc parameters

Tags: jaxb, xsd, private, unmarshalling, protected

Is there any way, xsd tags for instance, to unmarshall xsd files to get private fields with accessor methods instead of protected fields which is the default behaviour? I have tried to search in the documentation but no avail.

I am aware of the plugin [plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377923/why-do-jaxb-generated-classes-have-protected-members-and-how-can-i-change-this?lq=1) solution here on stackoverflow but I would like to have a xsd-tag or a built-in solution on existing technologies, not extra things to handle like writing a plugins that requires extra maintenance cost =)

Comment: JAXB can unmarshal to private fields.  The fields generated from an XML Schema are protected.  Are you asking how to generate private fields?

Comment: Yes, I am looking specifically for inline xsd/jaxb xml fragments to include in the xsd file to acheive this on the xsd artifact only OR if there are undocumented jaxb (using xjc) parameters that can achieve the same OR if there some even more smart solution

Comment: I think the new more narrow question make the duplicate tag obsolete OR ...

Comment: The linked question is:  Why are protected fields generated and how to change it to private?  Your question is:  How to change it to private?  The other question has a good answer, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Now I have also updated the question heading, good point.

Comment: I have reopened the question.