# Generate Java classes with a visibility of 'private' instead of 'protected'

Tags: java, jaxb, wsimport

I have a wsdl and I am generating the associated Java classes using **wsimport** (from the jdk).

The generated Java classes have their fields visibility set to **protected**.

How do you generate those Java classes with a visibility of **private** ?

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377923/why-do-jaxb-generated-classes-have-protected-members-and-how-can-i-change-this) but the solution is to write a plugin.
Since I am also using an jaxb binding file to correct some few other things ,I m looking for a declarative way to switch from protected to private.

Thank you

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no such built-in way at the moment. What is the problem with the plugin and the bindings file?

Comment: It's just that I wanted more like a declarative way but if there is no such built in way, I will try using the plugin's example. Thanks.